# rpmbuild: define directory as source file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Is it possible to define a directory with files in it as a source? I set the following in my `.spec` file:

```
...
Source0: file1
Source1: mydir/x1.txt
Source2: mydir/x2.txt
...

%install
install -D -m 0644 %{S:0} %{buildroot}%{_sbindir}/file1
install -D -m 0644 %{S:3} %{buildroot}%{_prefix}/local/etc/mydir/x1.txt
install -D -m 0644 %{S:4} %{buildroot}%{_prefix}/local/etc/mydir/x2.txt

%files
%{_sbindir}/file1
%{_prefix}/local/etc/mydir/x1.txt
%{_prefix}/local/etc/mydir/x2.txt
...
```

However `rpmbuild` fails:

```
install: cannot stat '/home/mrv/rpmbuild/SOURCES/x1.txt': No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.NXmITb (%install)
```

Is there no way to tell rpmbuild that I want files from SOURCES/mydir/* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope; it must be a tarball / zip file / etc. [This link](https://github.com/AaronDMarasco/rpm-cookbook#importing-a-pre-existing-file-tree) walks you thru the steps to tar it up.

Comment: Thanks for link. Could you answer a few questions? I think I understand the trick with `tar`, however I'm unsure what exactly happens in `%install` section -- why there is two `cp` happening?

Comment: @Mark the "echo" in the line before explains it; it is attempting to hardlink the files (`cp -l`), but if that fails it will attempt to copy instead. I do that to save time/space when packaging large files.